# Crystal reports Displaying column data in one row

Tags: crystal-reports

I want to display few rows of data in a one column and i am using the below 3 formula method:

Group header

```
WhilePrintingRecords; 
Shared StringVar hazards := "";
If Not InRepeatedGroupHeader Then
    hazards := "";
```

Detail section

```
WhilePrintingRecords;
if  ( {CARRIERLOADBYJOB.REDUNDANT_STOCK_ID}   in   StringVar hazards ) 
then 
StringVar hazards := hazards 
else 
StringVar hazards := hazards + {CARRIERLOADBYJOB.REDUNDANT_STOCK_ID}    + ',  '  ;
```

Footer section

```
WhilePrintingRecords;
if  length(trimright(StringVar hazards)) > 1  
then
StringVar hazards
else
StringVar hazards := left(hazards, (length(trimright(hazards)) - 1));
```

expected result is
80045,85263

but i am getting a result as 8920,5269,80045,85263

few additional records from the different is getting accumulated for the result. any help to omit the additional records

Comment: Use record selection formula?

Comment: How are you filtering the required data